# ts-node-dev no compila luego de module augmentation

Tags: nodejs, typescript

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con socket.io y express con TypeScript, ts-node-dev para el desarrollo. Utilizo un middleware de autenticación de socket.io para verificar un jwt que viene en la conexión, rechaza si no es válido, si lo es entonces agrega a la información del socket la prop "user", como esta prop no existe en el tipo de daato de socket.io hago un module augmentation para agregarlo.

Todo funciona correctamente, el module augmentation funciona y tengo acceso a la prop user tanto en el middleware como en el socket, el problema es que ts-node-dev no detecta el cambio en el módulo por lo que lanza un error de compilación. Noté que si utilizo *// @ts-ignore* justo antes de acceder a la prop user entonces compila correctamente y todo funciona normal, pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de evitar hacer esto.

Aquí mi configuración de tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    },
    "typeRoots": [
      "./types",
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Aclarar que Typescript no se **compila**, se **transpila**.